# Prevent autorun VBA code when opening a file

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'm facing a problem where I have written a User form where I have provided the `application.visible = false` in the workbook program sheet under `on_open`, now I'm able to run the program but I'm unable to open the workbook or the VBA program.

Please help

Thank you and Regards,
Nagarjun B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent autorun VBA code like `Workbook_Open` or `Auto_Open` click File › Open from the menu/ribbon, select your file and **hold down the shift key** when you click the Open button.

For a detailed how-to also see here: [Preventing auto_open and Workbook_Open events from running](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/preventopenevent.asp).

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me.