# Strange behavior using custom shortcut keys in excel

Tags: excel, vba

When executing a subroutine via a custom shortcut key set in either Alt+F8 or using the VBA code:

```
Application.OnKey "+^{o}", "open_all_DI_logs"
```

I get different behavior when assigning it with Shift or without.

```
Application.OnKey "^{o}", "open_all_DI_logs"
```

Executes the code all they way to the end. However,

```
Application.OnKey "+^{o}", "open_all_DI_logs"
```

Stops after the first workbook in the for i loop when it should open from 19 to 15.

If I keep pressing Ctrl+Shift+o it opens the next unopened workbook then stops.

This is the code I am attempting to run:

```
Public Sub open_all_DI_logs()
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbk As Workbook
    Dim path As String
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim i As Long

    For i = FiscalYear(2) To 15 Step -1
        ' See if the workbook is open
        For Each wb In Workbooks
            If wb.Name = "RI" & i & ".xlsm" Then
                found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next wb

        If found = False Then
            ' Workbook is not open
            path = "path"
            Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path, writerespassword:="pw", ignorereadonlyrecommended:=True)
            Set wbk = Nothing
        End If

        If found = True Then found = False
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function FiscalYear(Optional float As Integer) As Integer
    ' It's October; start the new fiscal year
    If Month(Date) >= 10 And Month(Date) <= 12 Then
        If float = 0 Then
            FiscalYear = Year(Date) + 1
        Else
            FiscalYear = CInt(Right(Year(Date) + 1, float))
        End If
    ' It's still the current fiscal year
    Else
        If float = 0 Then
            FiscalYear = Year(Date)
        Else
            FiscalYear = CInt(Right(Year(Date), float))
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

If I debug>step into or F8 in VBAE all the way through, there are no issues. Run sub or F5 in VBAE has no issues either.

I have other subs that act the same way when assigning a shortcut key with or without the Shift key.

Is this normal behavior? Or is my code just shite?

Comment: Holding Shift while opening a workbook is supposed to [prevent auto execution of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45192399/11683) in that workbook. Apparently that affects the calling code too.